# Android prevent time consuming loading of WebView

Tags: java, android, android-webview, webviewclient, android-websettings

I used android 'WebView' to load the url content. The loading process is time consuming than that url loading in browser.

Below is my code:

**actvitity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_web_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/agreement_webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layoutMode="opticalBounds"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView agreementWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        agreementWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.agreement_webView);

        loadAgreementWebView();

    }

    public void loadAgreementWebView(){

        String url = "http://my-url/";

        if (!url.equals("") || !url.isEmpty() || !url.equals("null")) {

            WebSettings settings = agreementWebView.getSettings();
            agreementWebView.setFocusable(true);
            agreementWebView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            agreementWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
            settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            settings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
            settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
            settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
            settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);


            settings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.4; Galaxy Nexus Build/IMM76B) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.133 Mobile Safari/535.19");
            //settings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");
            agreementWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

            agreementWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
            agreementWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

            agreementWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    Log.d("NEWS_WEB_VIEW", "Processing webview url click...");
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }

                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    Log.d("NEWS_WEB_VIEW", "Finished loading URL: " +url);

                }

                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    Log.d("NEWS_WEB_VIEW", "Error: " + description);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                public void onReceivedSslError(final WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, final SslError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
                    handler.proceed();
                }

                public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url)
                {
                    Log.d("NEWS_WEB_VIEW", "onLoadResource" + view.getUrl()+" : "+url);

                }
            });

            agreementWebView.loadUrl(url);
            Log.d("NewsWebViewActivity","NEWS_URL: "+url);

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "There is no URL to load", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

**AndroidMenifest.xml**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

The issue is when loading a page (my-url) in 'Webview' it's taking more than 10 seconds to load. Otherwise when loading the page (my-url) in 'Browser' it's taking less than 3 seconds to load. What I need to do is load the 'my-url' content quicker than present like as browser.

Answer (score 0):

After removing some 'WebView' settings, and inserting this line

```
agreementWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
```

It's loading fine.

**Removed follwing**

```
        settings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);

        settings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.4; Galaxy Nexus Build/IMM76B) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.133 Mobile Safari/535.19");
        //settings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");
        agreementWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
        agreementWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```